# Jellyfish 22.04 - Suspending laptop causes black screen with bluetooth failure

Tags: bluetooth, suspend, 22.04

I upgraded my ThinkPad to Jellyfish 22.04, and now after every time I suspend or close the lid, after starting it again, I get a black screen with a Bluetooth failure.

Not exact, but is something like this:

```
Bluetooth: hcio: Suspend notifier action (3) failed: -110
```

What could cause this? And how come Bluetooth can cause the system to not boot up after suspension?

Comment: On my Lenovo legion5 the same, coming from suspend.
This is the exact error: Bluetooth: hcio: Timed out waiting for suspend events Bluetooth: hcio: Suspend timeout bit: 6 Bluetooth: hcio: Suspend notifier action (3) failed: -110 The screen then goes black, and I have to force reboot.
After reboot, Bluetooth works fine.

Comment: This may work: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1429462/bluetooth-hci0-timeout-waiting-for-suspend-events/1441371#1441371