# Bluetooth hci0: Timeout waiting for suspend events

Tags: bluetooth, suspend, 22.04

Often, when waking up my computer, it wont let itself wake up, instead it shows me the following message:

```
Bluetooth hci0: Timeout waiting for suspend events
Bluetooth hci0: Suspend timeout bit: 6
Bluetooth hci0: Suspend notifier action (3) failed: -110
```

This happens randomly, sometimes several times a day, sometimes not for a week, but it has happened for ages (also already in 20.04).

Is there any intelligent way to debug this and get rid of that error?

Comment: If the Bluetooth can be turned off by a switch or if a dongle remove it before waking the machine so it wont have to wait for the Bluetooth to wake up is one thought.

Comment: Yeah, in theory, that is working, but in practice, it is a bit unhandy to crawl under the desk, remove the dongle, suspend the computer and then put it in again for using the bluetooth mouse.

Answer (score 6):

I solved the same issue by turning off the bluetooth before suspending as suggested above, but automatically with a script which also restore bluetooth afterwards

Just add the following file (and make it executable):

/usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/bluetooth.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

if [[ $1 == "pre" ]]
then
    /usr/sbin/rfkill block bluetooth
elif [[ $1 == "post" ]]
then
    /usr/sbin/rfkill unblock bluetooth
fi
```

It worked a treat on my Dell XPS15.

Comment: I had the same problem. But I didn't read your answer carefully and missed to make the script executable: `$ sudo chmod a+x /usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/bluetooth.sh`

Answer (score 2):

I used Se6's script, but ran into

```
usb usb1-port14: disabled by hub (ENI?), re-enabling...
hci0: HCI reset during shutdown failed
```

followed by a computer freeze on Ubuntu 22.04 ThiknPad x1 extreme gen 1.

Instead of using

```
/usr/sbin/rfkill block bluetooth
/usr/sbin/rfkill unblock bluetooth
```

I'm using on suspend:

```
/bin/systemctl stop bluetooth
```

and on resume:

```
/bin/systemctl start bluetooth
```